# Number of paths from vertex A or B or C to G or H or I

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, permutations

I am trying to find in how many ways I can get from any of A,B,C to any of G,H,I in the graph shown bellow visiting exactly n vertices without repeating any vertex. I have tried creating an adjacency matrix and setting the n as the exponent then adding up all the values at the bottom left corner where A,B,C and G,H,I intersect but this is giving me different values to the ones I calculated manually so I don't know where I went wrong and what I should be doing to solve this problem effectively.

[image: Graph]

The overall aim of solving this problem is to find an equation that given the "side length" (number of vertices on one row) in a graph that has the same square structure as the one above and a the size of the paths returns how many different paths there is.

Comment: is probably giving you bigger numbers because the formula of the matrix exponentiation does not distinguish that you do not want to repeat vertices. Unless you give the graph an orientation.

Comment: @Phicar is there any way to adapt that matrix exponentiation to not repeat vertices?

Comment: What does "repeating a vertex more than once" mean? If we go from A to G by ADEDG then D is repeated only once, right? Because the first visit to D is not a repeat?

Comment: @bof i have edited, it was meant to be "without reaping a vertex." so the example you gave would be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is small enough that you can do this dynamic programming. Let `num(start, end, n, mask)` denote the number of paths, where

- `start` is the start vertex,
- `end` is the end vertex,
- `n` is the length of the path, and
- `mask` is a subset of the $9$ vertices; the vertices in this subset are prohibited from being used in the path. For your problem, you want $\text{mask}=\varnothing$, but intermediate calculations will have nonempty masks.

Then it follows that

- `num(end, end, n, mask) = 1 if n = 0, 0 otherwise.`
- If `start != end`, then `num(start, end, n, mask)` is the sum of `num(neighbor, end, n-1, mask U {start})`, where `neighbor` ranges over the neighbors of `start` which are not in mask.

Really, this is just using depth first search to trace out all possible paths. Since you want paths from any vertex in the first row to any vertex in the last row, you need to add up nine values with all possible `start` and `end` vertices as inputs.

Comment: Alternatively, you can introduce a dummy source node that is adjacent to A, B, and C, introduce a dummy sink node that is adjacent to G, H, and I, and compute the paths from source to sink.

Comment: This would definitely work, I have coded a similar program, however what my aim really is, is to find a function to describe the number of paths for a given dimension, since i will then be using it to find some limits. This program helps me check the function works but it doesn't solve the problem of extremely large graphs.